# Issues with fixing an object to a camera

Tags: c++, opengl, camera

I'm having some issues attaching a model of a gun to the camera, so that as the player in my game walks/looks around, the gun is always pointing forward (as in most FPS games).

I can translate the gun to a position in the scene just fine, and also have it follow the player's movement, but at the expense of the its scale and rotation returning to the defaults.

I can place the gun in the scene with the right size and pointing forward and slightly up. I can change the translate line so  that the gun follows the movement, but rotation and scale are reset.

Comment: If you want the gun to always stay in front of the camera, you can simply leave away the cameramatrix and just define the modelmatrix as if the camera stands at the origin.

Comment: @BDL - How exactly would I go about that? Not quite sure what you mean. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, the view matrix is the inverse of the model matrix the camera would have. To place a object always in front of the camera, the model matrix of this object has to be the camera model matrix times a relative translation.

But this can be optimized a lot: Let's assume for the start, that the camera can only be translated, but not rotated. We donate the position of the camera in world space as `T_C`. Now the camera matrix will be `View = Translate(-T_C)`.

Let's now assume we always want to have a gun that is `t_G` units in front of the camera. Then the world space position of the gun object would be `T_G = T_C + t_G` and the model matrix would be `Model = Translate(T_G)`.

Let's now write down what happens in total when trying to render the gun object:

```
MVP = Projection * View * Model
    = Projection * Translate(-T_C) * Translate(T_G)
    = Projection * Translate(-T_C) * Translate(T_C + t_G)
```

Since translations can be spit in several consecutive translations we can write

```
    = Projection * Translate(-T_C) * Translate(T_C) * Translate(t_G)
```

, where we see that the second and third matrix cancel each other out since `Translate(-T_C) * Translate(T_C) = Identity`, which means, that we can completely leave away all view matrices and just use a model matrix with the relative translations to the camera:

```
MVP = Projection * Translate(t_G)
    = Projection * ModelRelative
```

The same basic principle also works when rotations of the camera are taken into account. We then have the camera described by the translation `T_C` and three rotations `R_Cx, R_Cy, R_Cz`. The camera matrix is then again the inverse of the cameras model matrix. (I will now use T() for translations and Rx() for rotations along a axis):

```
View = inverse(T(T_C) * Rz(R_Cz) * Ry(R_Cy) * Rx(R_Cx))
     = Rz(-R_Cz) * Ry(-R_Cy) * Rx(-R_Cx) * T(-T_C)
```

A object that is again placed at a constant distance in front of the camera would have to have a model matrix similar to above:

```
Model = T(T_C) * Rz(R_Cz) * Ry(R_Cy) * Rx(R_Cx) * T(t_G)
```

When now multiplying everything together for `MVP`, again all terms except of `T(t_G)` vanish.

In conclusion, this means, that all camera parameters are irrelevant for placing an object always in front of the camera. We can just leave away the view matrix and let the model matrix just contain the transformations relative to the camera. Another way to think of it is as a special camera placed in the origin which is only used for rendering the gun. Kind of when we would first make a photo of the world as we want to see it, then a photo of a gun in a green-room  and photoshop everything together at the end.

Comment: Thanks! This really cleared up some of my misconceptions about the different Matrices.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Feel free to upvote if the answer helped you.